# Javascript weird parseFloat

Tags: javascript

initializing a Google Map canvas, I have a weird zoom value being set ...

```
//Google Map
function initialize(){
  var mapCanvas = $('.map-canvas');

  mapCanvas.each(function () {
        var $this           = $(this),
                zoom            = 10,
                lat             = 45.426340,
                lng             = 0.085172,
                scrollwheel     = false,
                draggable       = true,
                title           = '',
                contentString   = '';

        if ($this.data('zoom')){
            zoom = parseFloat($this.data('zoom'));
            alert('zoom: ' + zoom);
        }
        ## will output :  zoom: 6 !!
        ## if a change to 

        if ($this.data('zoom')){
            #zoom = parseFloat($this.data('zoom'));
            zoom = 10;
        }
        ## then I get my zoom at the value 10...
```

What could be wrong ? anything related with the `parseFloat()` ??

Comment: If you log `$this.data('zoom')` what do you get, it doesn't look like it's defined in the above code ?

Comment: What is expected value ?

Comment: `parseFloat(10) === 10`

Comment: `$this.data('zoom')` will return the `data-zoom`  value related with `.map-canvas` and not the zoom variable value, if it return 6 that because your `map-canvas` has `data-zoom="6"`.

Comment: Yes... thanks for your feedback... I was reading the .js of this template ( with the default values...) not the .html code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this.data('zoom')` has nothing to do with `var zoom = 10;`

You are actually referring to the attribute `data-zoom` of each `mapcanvas` element